# Using Ticket Cache in Kafka Producer Java API

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-producer-api, jaas

I want to write a Java application that uses the Ticket cache of a client, instead of using a Keytab file. The examples that I found yet work all with a JAAS config that defines the Keytab and principal (useTicketCache=false).

I tried to use the following JAAS content (kafka_client.jaas):

```
KafkaClient {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=false
  useTicketCache=true
  serviceName=kafka;
};
```

In my Java application I set this JAAS with following command:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "kafka_client.jaas");

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "my-server.de:6667");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
props.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka");

KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test_topic", "key", "value")).get();
```

This does not work and aborts with the following exception:

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information from the user
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    [...]
```

As explained above, I only found examples that used the principal + keytab way without using ticket cache. This way also works for me, but it is not the way that I need/want to go...

Is it possible to use ticket cache in my Kafka client Java application at all? Or is the keytab way the only possibility? Thank you!

Comment: Did you `kinit` before calling your producer? Optionally, you could also add `doNotPrompt=true` to your jaas.conf, but that shouldnt matter as long as you have valid ticket in credentials cache.

Comment: Yes I'm doing a `kinit` before creating/using the Producer.

Comment: set useTicketCache=false, and provide keytab path.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Kafka Client bug or kafka developers don't know what is kerberos flood.
If you will use keytab param then your KDC (Active Directory or Redhat FreeIPA) infrastucture will be attacked by redundant requests.

keytab JAAS property isn't fit for Linux and Windows because JAAS doesn't support credential cache direct support and cannot store TGS tickets. It is popular issue for Java.

JGSS can help you to get all Kerberos features and increase authentication speed for 5x:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/accessing-native-gss-api.html
It avoids to use doubtful oracle module against Sun as years-proven RFC compatible one.
Don't forget to export KRB5CCNAME for unique username ccache and KRB5_KTNAME for keytab.